# SMTPClient MFE Proxy Error

Tags: c#, .net

I keep on getting this error when I try to send mail using smtp client  c# .net 5.0. 'Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available'. Any one has an idea why?

Comment: Post more details of the SMTP you're using.

Comment: <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="sender@sender.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" password="*****" userName="*****" port="587" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>